# Where can I find out which exact version(s) of the SDK apple is currently accepting for distribution?

Tags: ios, distribution

Is there a reliable, up-to-date, resource, listing all of the exact version numbers for SDKs that apple currently accepts for distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you should generally assume that Apple expect you to release using the most recent non-beta SDK (iOS 5 at the moment, but iOS 5.1 will be out of beta shortly). You might get away with releasing an app built with the 4.3 SDK, at least for a few more months, but why risk it? - why do you want to deploy with an earlier SDK?

If it's because you still want to support iOS 4 then it is not necessary to build with an older SDK to support older iOS versions - just set your deployment target to iOS 4.

If it's because you want to be able to test older iOS versions in the simulator, it's possible to install the latest SDK in its own folder so that you can still test older iOS versions in the simulator but also build apps using the latest SDK.

If it's because some specific piece of code in your app breaks under the iOS 5 SDK, you'll have to bite the bullet and fix it eventually so it may as well be now. Or just post what's broken on StackOverflow and we'll fix it for you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

On the developer site, when you log in, there's this section:

[image: Apple dev section]

I chose the left most link when I want to submit.  Lately, they won't let you submit when you use what's on the right to submit.

Good luck!

Comment: They've never let you submit with beta SDK versions. When the beta enters gold master Apple will send an email stating that you can submit apps using the beta/GM SDK, but the rest of the time you should assume it's not allowed.